# Resize TilePane Cell

Tags: javafx

I bind the `Tile Property` to make the `HomeTabCell` dynamic adjust their width and height value. However the width and height of `HomeTabCell` keep the same.

That is a way to make it work or should I use `GridPane` instead?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < room.getMaxPlayers(); i++) {
            try {
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/HomeTabCell.fxml"));
                    tilePane.getChildren().add(fxmlLoader.load());
                  tilePane.prefTileWidthProperty().bind(centerRoomHBox.widthProperty().divide(2).subtract(3));
                    tilePane.prefTileHeightProperty().bind(centerRoomHBox.heightProperty().divide(6 / 2));
                    HomeTabCell box = (HomeTabCell) fxmlLoader.getController();
                    box.setInfo(null, room.getMaxPlayers());
           } catch (IOException ex) {
                     bugsnag.notify(ex);
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make `anchorPane` from `HomeTabCell` `public` then bind width and height values.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < room.getMaxPlayers(); i++) {
                        try {
                                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/HomeTabCell.fxml"));
                                tilePane.getChildren().add(fxmlLoader.load());
                              tilePane.prefTileWidthProperty().bind(centerRoomHBox.widthProperty().divide(2).subtract(3));
                                tilePane.prefTileHeightProperty().bind(centerRoomHBox.heightProperty().divide(6 / 2));
                                HomeTabCell box = (HomeTabCell) fxmlLoader.getController();
                                box.anchorPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(centerRoomHBox.widthProperty().divide(2).subtract(3));
box.anchorPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(centerRoomHBox.heightProperty().divide(6 / 2));
                                    box.setInfo(null, room.getMaxPlayers());
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                     bugsnag.notify(ex);
                           }
                }
```